# Semantic UI - Make accordion call a function on click?

Tags: javascript, function, click, accordion, semantic-ui

I've got an accordion working in my code.  However, I was wondering if there was any way to make an accordion call a function whenever it is clicked.  I'm hoping it will be possible to a link a function to a click event when the accordion is initialized.

For example, you can set a selector to to change what triggers the basic functionality of the accordion like this:

```
$('.ui.accordion').accordion({
    selector: {
        trigger: '.button'
    }
});
```

Is there something similar I can do to call a function?  Maybe something like:

```
$('.ui.accordion').accordion({
    onClick: {
        function: 'myFunc'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your accordian layout, but something like this could work:

```
$(".ui .accordion .tab").click(function(){
    /* function goes in here */
    });
});
```

If this isn't the correct structure just paste a link to the site as a reply and I will fix my answer up!

Comment: Ah yes you're right, I can just do something like that.  For some reason, I was thinking this was some special Semantic UI thing, but we can just use normal jQuery stuff as well.  Thanks!